# jQuery Dropdown Show/Hide div not work fine

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use the following code which works well. I'm doing a CRUD operation. When I create an object then it works very well. However when I want to edit then this input field was hidden. I want to hide and show based on values.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // debugger;
  $('#isRequested').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "true" && $(this).val() != "select") {
      $('.entity').show();
    } else {
      $('.entity').hide();
    }
  })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#isApproved').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "true" && $(this).val() != "select") {
      $('#denial').show();
    } else {
      $('#denial').hide();
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label class="col-form-label text-lg-left" asp-for="IsPreviouslyRequestedAssistance"></label>
      <select class="form-control click" id="isRequested" asp-for="IsPreviouslyRequestedAssistance">
        <option value="select">Please Select</option>
        <option value="true">Yes</option>
        <option value="false">No</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 entity showup" style="display:none">
      <label id="EntityName" class="col-form-label " asp-for="EntityName"></label>
      <input type="text" id="EntityName" asp-for="EntityName" class="form-control" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 row entity" style="display: none">
    <div class="col-md-4 ">
      <label asp-for="WasApproved" class="col-form-label"></label>
      <select id="isApproved" class="form-control " asp-for="WasApproved">
        <option value="select">Please Select</option>
        <option value="true">Yes</option>
        <option value="false">No</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" id="denial" style="display: none">
      <label asp-for="ReasonForDenial" class="col-form-label"></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="ReasonForDenial">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can you tell me what should I do?

Comment: Your code appears to be working as expected. Your goal isn't clear from the description in the question. Could you please edit it to make what you're trying to achieve more understandable.

Comment: I have 2 dropdown list, which contains two values, true and false, first dropdown list value is true then an input field, and another dropdown list is shown. If the Last drawdown list value is false then show another input field. All work well.

But When I go to the edit page for editing, then it only shows the first dropdown list value, But I want to show the first dropdown list value and input field and the last dropdown list value.

Maybe I do not describe it clearly...

Comment: Ok - so in that case what does your code looks like which builds the edit page? Set the visibility states of the relevant inputs there

Comment: Yes, you are right